# NopCommerce v2.65 change invoce pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, nopcommerce

I am working with nopcommre version 2.65 and my question is just;
is there an easy way to change the auto generated invoice pdf?
There are some things that i have to add and the only way i have now is to put it all in the logo that you can upload to the invoice.

Any ideas?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

In Nop-Commerce 2.65 invoice  pdf is generated by using **iTextSharp** libaery if you want to change the invoice formatte then you need to modified iTextSharp code which is written in

```
PDFServer.cs in (Nop.Services.Common) **PrintOrdersToPdf** methods.
```

i think that is only way if you want to change PDF for matte in NOP2.65 
for more details for designing by using iTextSharp refer http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables

Comment: if you have PDF template then you can write you values in that, it reduce effort to creating pdf through code.

Comment: aha, ok...i will have a look at that...thanx for your help so far!

Comment: i have had a look around and the only way to really edit the pdf invoice is to change in the source code! You can add logo to it from admin-panel.. thats it! This may change in future versions..hopefully!

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes you can do it ineased  taking nopcommerce logo you can provide a interface in admin area where you can upload a image save it in database and use that image in PDF code....